# Find a herbrand model for $\forall x((p(x)\to\lnot p(f(x))) \land (\lnot p (f(f(x)))\to p(f(x))))$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

$\forall x((p(x)\to\lnot p(f(x))) \land (\lnot p (f(f(x)))\to p(f(x))))$

So the domain would be the herbrand universe. $p(x)=1 $ iff $x=f(a)$ where $a$ is a constant.

Is what im saying correct ? Would this be a correct herbrand model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case there is one function symbol $f$. So the Herbrand universe should be the infinite set of syntactic terms
$$
\{a, f(a), f(f(a)), f(f(f(a))), \ldots\}.
$$
Now, we have to decide what to choose for $p$ in order to make the statement true.

You have suggested that we take $p(f(a)) = \text{true}$ and for all other $x$, $p(x) = \text{false}$. This will satisfy the first part of the statement: $\forall x((p(x)\to\lnot p(f(x)))$. But it will not satisfy the second part, namely $(\lnot p (f(f(x)))\to p(f(x))))$.

- Can you think of an example, why it does not satisfy the second part?
- How can we correct your choice of $p$, so that both the first and second part are true?

Comment: We could set $p(f(a))$ to true aswell ?

Comment: Excuse me im very confused. Why would the first part be satisfied ?

Comment: Would something like $p(a)=0 , p(f(a))=1, p(f(f(a)))=0, p(f(f(f(a)))))=1$ etc work ????

Comment: @asddf I made some typos. $p(f(a))$ is true is what I meant. But your latest comment is exactly right!